# Using Enum value which is already #define'd

Tags: c++

I have an enum, which defines `Countrycode` which is in ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 format. 
But somewhere in the third party includes, there is a #define, which defines IN. 
(For example, C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared\minwindef.h).

```
#ifndef IN
#define IN
#endif
```

Now my country code Enum says I cannot define country code `IN` .

Any idea?

Comment: you have to rename your enum because this prefedined IN will be overwriten over the `Countrycode` enum definition

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve]. The solution is however usually to exert tight control of what you include where.

Comment: I don't think you could override something that is already defined.

Comment: @BladeMight Could - but shouldn't, for their own sanity and hapiness... I am trying for decades to keep my colleagues from doing `#ifdef IN #undef IN #endif #define IN`.

Comment: but then the country code enum cannot be 'ISO_3166-1_alpha-2', huh!

Comment: @Yunnosch that was my first thought! Wondering any other way out!

Comment: Use `#ifndef MYHEADERCALLED_IN_H #define MYHEADERCALLED_IN_H`. Short "good" names are always a trap.

Comment: Do you need these to be compile time value?  If not you can use a `std::map<std::string, int>`

Comment: If you can use c++11 or later, what about using an `enum class` instead of a plain `enum`?

Comment: Or is your side the enum? Then `#define MYENUMVALUECALLED_IN`. Yes I am exaggerating. The point is, in C you need to use names nobody else uses in the same include-visibility context and that is easier with longer identifiers. By the way, the person to blame is the one which defines the extremely short `IN` and then devilishly distributes that to other hitherto clean poor souls.

Comment: The real solution is to get whoever wrote `#define IN` to go back and change it. It's not reasonable to reserve such a short and potentially common identifier across all namespaces. Alternatively you can change your `enum` to not collide with the naming conventions of `#define`s (if your organisation has such naming conventions).

Comment: The `IN` (and `OUT`) macros are used for readability of parameters in function declarations.  The simple fix is to just `#undef IN` after including all the system headers.  The (probably better) fix is to prefix all you country codes, something like `CC_IN`.

Comment: @JimsonKannantharaJames Why do you even want this? Are you sure you don't need something like `#define Country_Code_IN "IN"`?

Comment: @Dominique nope, the enum is a list of all country codes which is in 'ISO_3166-1_alpha-2' format.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Silly Microsoft guys wrote it and burnt it into Windows SDK, no way out! Changed my enum to `IN_`

Comment: @JimsonKannantharaJames Well, that's a shame. The standard explicitly reserves identifiers for those guys but they don't use them. For example, `_IN` would have been fine, nobody else is allowed to use that for any purpose. But maybe the WINAPI predates those identifier reservations. Edit : One thing I like to do with `<windows.h>` is to only include it once in a dedicated wrapper header where I can fix stuff like that (such as `#undef IN`, excluding `min` and `max`, etc.) and then only include *that* header when I need OS stuff.

Comment: Simply `#undef` it.